# In TypeScript. Why 'this' keyword value is undefined when the function get called from function variable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
export class Http {

     m1(s:string) {
       console.log("in m1",s);
     }

     m2(s:string) {
       console.log("in m2",s);
     }

}

export class a{

     http=new Http();

     op(s:string) {
        console.log(this);
        this.http.m1(s+"from a");
     }

}

export class b {

      http=new Http();

      constructor() { }

      op1(s:string) {
        console.log(this);
        this.http.m2(s+"from b");
      }

}

//main function call
let v = 2
let ptr = null;
let a1 = new a();
let b1 = new b();

switch(v) {
    case 1:
      ptr=a1.op;
      break;

    case 2:
      ptr=b1.op1;
      break;
}

ptr("s");
```

here in the above example, I have created a & b class has op & op1 method respectively. on the basis of my choice(like in switch statement) I want to call a method. but I get an error 'Cannot read property 'http' of undefined'. 
Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because doing `ptr = a1.op; ptr("s");` is fundamentally different from doing `a1.ptr("s");`

`this` value depends from where you call the function. In case you call `ptr("s")`, it's an equivalent of `window.ptr("s")` so `this` is `window` in sloppy mode, `undefined` in strict mode (for more details on strict and sloppy modes, please read the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode))

When you call the function from an object, `this` is the object that's why `a1.op("s")` will work because `this` will be `a1`

Comment: Trying to put it more succinctly: the value of `this` is decided at *calltime* and will be set to the thing before the `.`. In `a.b()`, `this` inside `b` will be `a`. No `a.`, no `this`.